# How to test if it is a list or a value in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

In a template in Django I am importing a list of dicts and in one of the keys (`tested`) I can have either a single value or a list of values depending on the case.
My context dict in the template looks something like this:

```
context_dicts.append({'url': p.url,
                      'type_': p.type,
                      'error': error,
                      'tested': p.tested})
```

In the html template I want to `if` test the `tested` key to do something if it is a single value and something else if it's a list. So when looping through the dicts, if I use `{% if value|length > 1% }` it will give me the string size of the value when it's just a value and the length of the list when it's a list. How can I test the if to tell me if it's a "list of one value" or more?

Comment: try `{% if tested|get_type == 'str' %}` or check `{{ tested|get_type }}`

Comment: the `tested|get_type` returns `<class 'str'>` and then apparently `{% if tested|get_type == 'str' %}` returns `False`. Any idea how to do the comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Storing possibly different kind of data in a single variables looks cumbersome to me. It makes your logic less easy to understand and may be prone to errors.

I think the best is to always store a list, but possibly a list with a single element. In the template, you could then do:

```
{% if tested.count == 1 %}
    do stuff with {{ tested.0 }} value
{% else %}
    do stuff with {{ tested }} list
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The thing is that I have multiple functions being exported to multiple templates with similar structure but one of the keys is sometimes a single value. But that's actually a good idea to have it always as a list!